# Vuetifyjs: how to make the v-stepper's step clickable?

Tags: javascript, vuetify.js, v-stepper

Using the [v-stepper](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/steppers) component, is there a way to make the steps respond to clicks?

P.S. On the link I provided, there is a Codepen example. It is a link to the official documentation so that example is always there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the props `editable` to your `v-stepper-step`.

[Example in Vuetify doc](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/steppers#example-editable)

---

About click event on `v-stepper-step`, it seems that `@click` is not triggered.

So, as a workaround you can watch the data you provide un your `v-stepper`'s `v-model` and alert on change or when you reach the wanted step. codepen.io/anon/pen/yReweK?editors=1011

[Workaround Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yReweK?editors=1011)

Comment: Thank you, how can I trigger, for example, an alert event by clicking on the first step?

Comment: Add `@click="methodThatPopAlert"` to your v-stepper-step props ?

Comment: It seems there is no way to trigger an event click. +1 for the info you shared though

Comment: As a workaround you can watch the data you provide un your `v-stepper`'s `v-model` and alert on change or when you reach the wanted step. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yReweK?editors=1011

Answer (score 1):

Listening to `@click.native` will work:

```
<v-stepper-step @click.native="alert('foo')"/>
```